# Finding possible combinations

Tags: permutations, combinations

Sorry if this isnt the right place to ask but heres my problem

I have a 6 digit combination that uses these 5 numbers (2,5,6,8,0). One of these numbers will have to be used twice. How would i go about getting a list of all possible combinations of these 5 numbers being used in a 6 digit combination

Comment: There are a lot of them... are you sure you want to *list* them and not count them?

Comment: There are $5\times \frac{6!}{2}=1800$ possible combinations.  Actually *listing* them can be accomplished using your favorite programming language and loops, perhaps most conveniently by using already existing libraries related to permutations, looping over the permutations of the characters $2,5,6,8,0,X$, replacing the $X$ with one of the characters that preceded it, skipping over the arrangements where $X$ appeared first.

Comment: As others have said, do you want to list them *by hand*, or by using a computer program, or just count the number of combinations?

Comment: Yep that went way over my head lol. Is there a calculator or something i can plug those numbers into to get a list of all possible combinations. I tried using a permutation with repetition  but i couldnt figure out how to restrict it to using all numbers and only having one repetition

Comment: Oh i want an actual list of all combinations

Comment: Here:https://www.dcode.fr/permutations-generator
Click on "Custom items list," then enter 6 digits so that 1 of those is repeated. For example: 2,2,5,6,8,0. Then repeat for the other digits.

Comment: Ok so do the calculation 5 times then combine the list to get a complete master list

Comment: Yes exactly. Make sure you click on "distinct permutations" only. You should get 360 combinations for each choice of a repeated digits, 1800 in total.

Answer (score 0):

Number of possible combinations are 5*(6!/2!) = 1800 (credit to @JMoravitz in the comments)

Here's a simple python code that provides you all combinations (you may run it [here](https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_python_compiler))

```
from itertools import permutations  

p = [2,5,6,8,0]
q = [2,5,6,8,0]

my_set = set()

index =0 
for i in q:
    p.append(i)
    perm = permutations(p,6) 

    for x in list(perm): 
        if x in my_set:
            continue

        my_set.add(x)
        print (index,x)
        index += 1

    p.remove(i)
```

snapshot result:

```
...
1784 (8, 5, 2, 6, 0, 0)                                                                                                                                                
1785 (8, 5, 6, 0, 2, 0)                                                                                                                                                
1786 (8, 5, 6, 0, 0, 2)                                                                                                                                                
1787 (8, 5, 6, 2, 0, 0)                                                                                                                                                
1788 (8, 6, 0, 2, 5, 0)                                                                                                                                                
1789 (8, 6, 0, 2, 0, 5)                                                                                                                                                
1790 (8, 6, 0, 5, 2, 0)                                                                                                                                                
1791 (8, 6, 0, 5, 0, 2)                                                                                                                                                
1792 (8, 6, 0, 0, 2, 5)                                                                                                                                                
1793 (8, 6, 0, 0, 5, 2)                                                                                                                                                
1794 (8, 6, 2, 0, 5, 0)                                                                                                                                                
1795 (8, 6, 2, 0, 0, 5)                                                                                                                                                
1796 (8, 6, 2, 5, 0, 0)                                                                                                                                                
1797 (8, 6, 5, 0, 2, 0)                                                                                                                                                
1798 (8, 6, 5, 0, 0, 2)                                                                                                                                                
1799 (8, 6, 5, 2, 0, 0)
```

- remember that the index start from position 0 (hence 1799+1 results)